# Joi validations function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, joi

I want to make a function to check that the email is unique among all the tables in the database so I will query on each table to check if the inputted email exists while validating the data using `joi`. I searched and found a code similar to this one

```
 email: Joi.string().email().lowercase().required().validate(function(value, done){
      console.log(value)//if this works i will query on  the database 
      done(null);
 })
```

However, it returns this error in postman

```
"error": {
    "generatedMessage": false,
    "name": "AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]",
    "code": "ERR_ASSERTION",
    "actual": false,
    "expected": true,
    "operator": "==",
    "path": "email.value"
}
```

I am trying to use the value so I could use my logic.

Comment: This message really makes it seem like the value you passed (the email) is not valid. Can you confirm that the email that's validated is valid?

Comment: @SamuelBolduc yes it is 100% valid. If i remove the `.validate` it passes normally.

Comment: if you want unique mail address, you can add sql constraints  and set the email column  `Unique`

Comment: @Afrida Anzum Aesha i do, but what i want is to make the email unique between more than one table.